# Qual a diferença entre override e :base em C#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre `override` e `:base` em C#

Existe alguma diferença ou tem a mesma função?

Answer (score 4):

Como o amigo Carltee respondeu. O modificador `override` serve para modificar ou estender uma função. Com isso você pode, ou não, alterar os comportamentos da Classe pai (ou classe base).

Para usar o `override` na classe filha você precisa indicar que a função pode ser modificada na classe pai. Para isso no c# utiliza-se o modificador `virtual`:

```
public class TestBase
{
    public virtual void Hello() {
        Console.WriteLine("Oi pai");
    }
}
```

Assim, o compilador entende que aquela função pode ser modificada na classe filha:

```
public class TestSon : TestBase
{
    public override void Hello() {
    //Exibe oi filho no console em vez de oi pai da classe base
        Console.WriteLine("oi filho");
    }
}
```

Nesse exemplo acima ele substitui a função da classe pai ao chamar a função pelo filho. Em vez de exibir "oi pai" exibe "oi filho.
Mas se ainda assim queremos executar a função da classe pai, utilizamos o modificador `base` que é como o modificador `super` em algumas linguagens. Com isso conseguimos acessar os métodos e propriedades da classe pai na classe filha:

```
public class TestFatherSon : TestBase
{
    public override void Hello() {
        //Exibe oi pai e oi filho no console, já que executa a função da classe pai
        base.Hello();
        Console.WriteLine("oi filho");
    }
}
```

Você pode ver o funcionamento na prática dos exemplos clicando no link abaixo. É uma ferramenta online que interpreta e compila código em c#:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPBq9j

Essa característica base também pode ser usada em funções construtoras. Que funciona da mesma forma. Se por algum motivo você precisar chamar o construtor da classe pai você utiliza `:base()` depois de declarar a função construtora na classe filho:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    int num;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass()");
    }

    public BaseClass(int i)
    {
        num = i;
        Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass(int i)");
    }

    public int GetNum()
    {
        return num;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // This constructor will call BaseClass.BaseClass()
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
    }

    // This constructor will call BaseClass.BaseClass(int i)
    public DerivedClass(int i) : base(i)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass md = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedClass md1 = new DerivedClass(1);
    }
}
```

Segue a documentação oficial da microsoft ao qual eu tirei o exemplo acima:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base

Answer (score 0):

Com o **override**, você pode modificar ou estender a implementação do método ou propriedade herdada, adicionando uma lógica diferente do que está na classe em que este foi herdado.

Já o **base** é simplesmente utilizado para acessar este método ou propriedade da classe base, não podendo modificar seu comportamento.

Comment: Utilize exemplos em código para facilitar o entendimento da sua explicação ;)